# Boootstrap 3 lightbox using modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am implementing a gallery using bootstrap on my website but the lightbox is not popping up for me when I click on a picture. I can't see any mistakes maybe you can. I can get the image in the gallery to show up but when I click on it, nothing happened. When the image is clicked, a lightbox with the picture and controls should show up.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">

        <!-- CSS: implied media=all -->
  <!-- CSS concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <style type="text/css">

    .modal-dialog {}

    .thumbnail {margin-bottom:6px;}

    .carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right{
      background-image:none;
      margin-top:10%;
      width:5%;
    }

  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
      /* copy loaded thumbnails into carousel */
    $('.row .thumbnail').on('load', function() {

    }).each(function(i) {
      if(this.complete) {
        var item = $('<div class="item"></div>');
        var itemDiv = $(this).parents('div');
        var title = $(this).parent('a').attr("title");

        item.attr("title",title);
        $(itemDiv.html()).appendTo(item);
        item.appendTo('.carousel-inner'); 
        if (i==0){ // set first item active
         item.addClass('active');
        }
      }
    });

    /* activate the carousel */
        $('#modalCarousel').carousel({interval:false});

    /* change modal title when slide changes */
        $('#modalCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
          $('.modal-title').html($(this).find('.active').attr("title"));
        });

    /* when clicking a thumbnail */
        $('.row .thumbnail').click(function(){
            var idx = $(this).parents('div').index();
            var id = parseInt(idx);
            $('#myModal').modal('show'); // show the modal
            $('#modalCarousel').carousel(id); // slide carousel to selected

        });
    });

  </script>
    </head>

    <body>          
        <div id="main" role="main">
            <br />
            <div class="page_title">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 align="center">ZZ ZZ</h1>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 1" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="img/123.jpg"></a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 2" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="img/carousel1.jpg"></a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 3" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/449955/FFF"></a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 4" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/992233"></a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 5" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/2255EE"></a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 6" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/449955/FFF"></a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 8" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/777"></a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 9" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/992233"></a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 10" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/EEE"></a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 11" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/449955/FFF"></a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 12" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/DDD"></a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 13" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/992233"></a></div>
           </div>
        </div>
<div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="carousel" id="modalCarousel">

          <div class="carousel-inner">



          </div>

          <a class="carousel-control left" href="#modaCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
          <a class="carousel-control right" href="#modalCarousel" data-

    slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">


        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />

        <!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if offline -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-2.1.1.min"><\/script>')</script>
      <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script defer src="js/plugins.js"></script>
      <script>
         (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
         (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
         m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
         })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

         ga('create', '', 'auto');
         ga('send', 'pageview');

      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have fixed it. There were a few (relatively minor) issues with your code, most notably a number of typos with the modals and redundant sets of JavaScript and CSS files. You should only ever import the Bootstrap files once, regardless of from what source you import them from. I think those issues, combined, were throwing things off. Note that I commented out the redundant lines in the below code and the [public Gist I published for you, which might be easier to read](https://gist.github.com/justathoughtor2/170a7aa8a4354a3cd9c7):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
<!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"> -->

<!-- CSS: implied media=all -->
<!-- CSS concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> -->

<style type="text/css">

.modal-dialog {}

.thumbnail {margin-bottom:6px;}

.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right{
background-image:none;
margin-top:10%;
width:5%;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
/* copy loaded thumbnails into carousel */
$('.row .thumbnail').each(function(i) {
  var item = $('<div class="item"></div>');
  var itemDiv = $(this).parents('div');
  var title = $(this).parent('a').attr('title');

  item.attr('title', title);
  item.append(itemDiv.html());
  $('.carousel-inner').append(item);
  if (i==0){ // set first item active
    item.addClass('active');
  }
});

/* activate the carousel */
// $('#modalCarousel').carousel({interval:false});

/* change modal title when slide changes */
$('#modalCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  $('.modal-title').html($(this).find('.active').attr("title"));
});

/* when clicking a thumbnail */
$('.row .thumbnail').click(function(){
    var idx = $(this).parents('div').index();
    var id = parseInt(idx);
    $('#myModal').modal('show'); // show the modal
    $('#modalCarousel').carousel(id); // slide carousel to selected

});
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main" role="main">
    <br />
    <div class="page_title">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 align="center">ZZ ZZ</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 1" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="img/123.jpg"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 2" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="img/carousel1.jpg"></a></div> -->
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 3" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x350/449955/FFF"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 4" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x350/992233"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 5" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x350/2255EE"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 6" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x350/449955/FFF"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 8" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x350/777"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 9" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x350/992233"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 10" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x350/EEE"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 11" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x350/449955/FFF"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 12" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x350/DDD"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 13" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x350/992233"></a></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
<h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="carousel" id="modalCarousel">

  <div class="carousel-inner">



  </div>

  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#modalCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#modalCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">


<button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br />
<br />

<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if offline -->
<!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-2.1.1.min"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script>
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
 (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
 m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
 })(window,document,'script','http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

 ga('create', '', 'auto');
 ga('send', 'pageview');

</script> -->
</body>
</html>
```